# Nginx Ingress controller and OCSP Must Staple

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, ocsp

Recently, I got a certificate from Let's Encrypt with the Must Staple extension on it, requiring a OCSP response to be sent with the certificate. I am using the kubernetes ingress-nginx(on Google Cloud) controller for TLS. The certificate is working great on Chrome(since it doesn't use OCSP), but it's failing on all other browsers because a OCSP response is not being stapled to it. The certificate I am using for the public key is the full certificate chain from Let's Encrypt. I'm not sure why nginx isn't attaching an OCSP response even though kubernetes supports OCSP.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look here: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/cmd/nginx/flags.go#L133-L137

It seems you either haven't got the full chain like you expected, or you're missing the "Authority Information Access" X.509 v3extension"